# Using PHPMailer to send attachments to the user based on the checkboxes they have checked?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, phpmailer

I need to send attachments based on the checkboxes the user has chosen in the form (it's to request manuals, and they can request more than one).

I've been reading older questions and apparently PHPMailer will save a lot of time and a lot of errors for attaching files, so I've gone for that option. Here's my code:

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="form-confirm">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="email"><br />
    Classic XL Parts: <input type="checkbox" name="document[]" value="ClassicXL" /><br />
    Racer 45 Parts: <input type="checkbox" name="document[]" value="Racing45" /><br />
    Flexer XL 45 Parts: <input type="checkbox" name="document[]" value="FlexerXL" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The PHP (I've added comments in to explain what I need to do):

```
    require_once '/php/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php'; 

    $files = array(
        'ClassicXL' => '/manuals/classic-xl-parts.pdf',
        'Racing45' => '/manuals/racing-45-parts.pdf',
        'FlexerXL' => '/manuals/flexer-xl-parts.pdf'
    );

    $checkboxesChecked = array(
     // Do I need to have another array that stores the checkboxes ticked? 
    );

    if(isset($_POST) && ($_POST['submit'] == 1)) {
        $email = new PHPMailer();
        $email->From      = 'webmaster@admin.com';
        $email->FromName  = 'Webmaster';
        $email->Subject   = 'Here are the files you requested:';
        $email->addAddress($_POST['email']);
        // My idea here, is that for every $checkboxesChecked, check through the $files 
        // for the corresponding file and attach to the email
        for ( ) { 
            $file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';
            $email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );

            return $email->Send();
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

As you can see from my comments I have a general idea of how to complete the task, I just need some help getting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you need:

```
$email->addAddress($_POST['email']);
if (array_key_exists('document', $_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST['document'] as $file) {
        if (array_key_exists($file, $files)) {
            $email->addAttachment($files[$file]);
        }
    }
}
//Don't send until you've attached everything
return $email->send();
```

A few other bits - check the return value from `addAddress` *before* you send in case you've been given an invalid address; if it fails to send, you'll probably want to retrieve some error information from `$email->ErrorInfo`.

Comment: Hi Synchro, so I was wrong in thinking I needed a second array to store which checkboxes are checked? I can't see anywhere else in the code that they do get checked.

Comment: To further elaborate, the only files that should send are the ones that have been checked in the checkboxes in the form. So I was thinking that needs to be checked somewhere, then stored in an array, then a foreach loop would "for each" checkbox ticked that exists in the $files array, add the attachment. If you understand what you mean? Are you able to edit your answer to help me with that part?

Comment: Because all your checkboxes have the same name attribute, any selection within them will turn up in `$_POST['documents']` in PHP. Stick a `var_dump($_POST);` at the top of your script and you'll see what I mean. My solution relies on the value attributes in your checkboxes exactly matching the indexes in your `$files` array, which is a reasonable approach. There's no need for a second array.

Comment: To be clear, `$_POST['document']` will only contain the items which have been checked. If none are checked it won't be submitted at all - I've updated the example to check that.

Comment: Hi @Synchro, would we be able to extend this to chat? The code is definitely valid but It still doesn't seem to be sending emails and I've got no errors in my log file either.

Comment: This check will never work: `$_POST['submit'] == 1` because in your form the submit element does not have a name attribute, and its value is `Submit`, not `1`.

Comment: I should have probably said this, but that part of the code has changed to - if (isset($_POST["submit"])) which should be valid, am I correct? So If I change the name attribute to 'submit' and the value to 'submit', lets see how we do

Comment: Managed to get the thing working! Marked as top answer for all the help, cheers @Synchro you're a champion!